# Natural isomorphism between $\tilde{H}_n(Y)$ and $H_n(Y, \{y\})$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $(Y, y)$ be a based space. How can I construct a natural isomorphism between $\tilde{H}_n(Y)$ and $H_n(Y, \{y\})$ for all $n \ge 0$ ?

My attempt at the problem is very convoluted. Either this is a very hard problem or I am not seeing something simple.

Comment: What is your definition of reduced homology groups? Taking the homology of the augmented chain complex?

Comment: @PaulFrost Hey, thanks for commenting. Yes, it is the homology group of the augmented chain complex.